# Adobe Air application fullscreen - HTML/XML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, air, fullscreen

Making my first Adobe Air app and was wondering if their was a fullscreen tag or javascript function to make the app fullscreen? I'm using HTML etc, not Flash.

Comment: Did you search on google before you posted this? Serious question. Here's the first result for *adobe air fullscreen*: http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_the_FullScreen_functionality_in_AIR-8004.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an Air application, you can control the fullscreen very well with the action script.

Please go through the StageDisplayState class for more information or just [visit this link](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_the_FullScreen_functionality_in_AIR-8004.html) as mentioned by [evan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848102/evan)

Comment: He's not looking for an ActionScript solution: my second link is points to a folder that contains -inside an HTML file- the code to do the same thing in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find an explanation and a file:

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_the_FullScreen_functionality_in_AIR-8004.html

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=getFile&fileId=3604